# Callback action when type registered with Simple Injector

Tags: inversion-of-control, mvvmcross, simple-injector

I need to be able to register a callback action for a specific type which will be called when the type is registered in the container. This is part of integration with a specialized framework.

```
void CallbackWhenRegistered<T>(Action action);
```

I'm looking for an optimal approach because I don't like to create an adapter to wrap all Register methods.

Is there any built-in functionality that can help trigger the provided action when a particular type is registered in the container?

Comment: There is no extension point for this. What is it you are trying to achieve; why do you need this?

Comment: I want to use SimpleInjector with MvvmCross. I need to implement IMvxIoCProvider [MvvmCross IoC](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/inversion-of-control-ioc#what-if-i-want-to-use-a-different-service-location-or-ioc-mechanism) ~adapter for SimpleInjector . For example I found [Autofac](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.MvvmCross/blob/develop/src/Autofac.Extras.MvvmCross/ChildAutofacMvxIocProvider.cs) implementation. You've created great library and MvvmCross will help to speed-up cross-platform development of my application. Is it possible to create such adapter?

Comment: It completely baffles me why MvvmCross would require to get notified when a registration occurs. It's interface is a [Conforming Container](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/conforming-container/). You might want to research to see how MvvmCross needs this behavior and if you can do without. If not, you can likely simulate this behavior by hand, because you know which types you are registering, and you can find out which notifications MvvmCross wants to see.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an (untested) adapter that might get you started:

```cs
public sealed class SimpleInjectorMvxIoCProvider : IMvxIoCProvider, IDisposable
{
    private readonly Container container;
    private readonly IServiceProvider provider;
    private readonly Scope scope;

    public SimpleInjectorMvxIoCProvider(Container container)
    {
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = ScopedLifestyle.Flowing;

        this.container = container;
        this.provider = container;
    }

    private SimpleInjectorMvxIoCProvider(Container container, Scope scope)
    {
        this.scope = scope;
        this.container = container;
        this.provider = container;
    }

    public void CallbackWhenRegistered<T>(Action action)
    {
    }

    public void CallbackWhenRegistered(Type type, Action action)
    {
    }

    public bool CanResolve<T>() where T : class =>
        this.container.GetRegistration<T>(throwOnFailure: false) != null;

    public bool CanResolve(Type type) =>
        this.container.GetRegistration(type, throwOnFailure: false) != null;

    public T Create<T>() where T : class => this.container.GetInstance<T>();

    public object Create(Type type) => this.container.GetInstance(type);

    public IMvxIoCProvider CreateChildContainer() =>
        new SimpleInjectorMvxIoCProvider(this.container, new Scope(this.container));

    public T GetSingleton<T>() where T : class => this.Create<T>();

    public object GetSingleton(Type type) => this.Create(type);

    public T IoCConstruct<T>() where T : class
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public T IoCConstruct<T>(IDictionary<string, object> arguments) where T : class
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public T IoCConstruct<T>(object arguments) where T : class
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public T IoCConstruct<T>(params object[] arguments) where T : class
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object IoCConstruct(Type type)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object IoCConstruct(Type type, IDictionary<string, object> arguments)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object IoCConstruct(Type type, object arguments)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object IoCConstruct(Type type, params object[] arguments)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RegisterSingleton<TInterface>(TInterface theObject) where TInterface : class =>
        this.container.RegisterInstance(theObject);

    public void RegisterSingleton(Type tInterface, object theObject) =>
        this.container.RegisterInstance(tInterface, theObject);

    public void RegisterSingleton<TInterface>(Func<TInterface> theConstructor) where TInterface : class =>
        this.container.RegisterSingleton(theConstructor);

    public void RegisterSingleton(Type tInterface, Func<object> theConstructor) =>
        this.container.RegisterSingleton(tInterface, theConstructor);

    public void RegisterType<TInterface>(Func<TInterface> constructor) where TInterface : class =>
        this.container.Register(constructor);

    public void RegisterType(Type t, Func<object> constructor) =>
        this.container.Register(t, constructor);

    public void RegisterType(Type tFrom, Type tTo) => this.container.Register(tFrom, tTo);

    public T Resolve<T>() where T : class => this.container.GetInstance<T>();

    public object Resolve(Type type) => this.container.GetInstance(type);

    public bool TryResolve<T>(out T resolved) where T : class
    {
        resolved = this.provider.GetService(typeof(T)) as T;
        return resolved != null;
    }

    public bool TryResolve(Type type, out object resolved)
    {
        resolved = this.provider.GetService(type);
        return resolved != null;
    }

    public void RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>()
        where TFrom : class
        where TTo : class, TFrom
    {
        this.container.Register<TFrom, TTo>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.scope != null)
        {
            this.scope.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            this.container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

After looking at the MvvmCross source code, I noticed there are just a few services that the framework is interested in getting notified about, which are:

- `IMvxValueConverterRegistry`
- `IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry`
- `IMvxTypeCache<View>`
- `IMvxNamespaceListViewTypeResolver`
- `IMvxValueCombinerRegistry`

Unless you are overriding these abstractions, there is no need to implement `CallbackWhenRegistered`.